# What's the meaning of the values in the OpenCV image representation?

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing

I am using OpenCV with Python. When I load a JPG or PNG image by calling `cv2.imread()`, I get a 2D matrix, whose size is the same as the resolution of that image. Each number in the matrix is in the range of 0 to 255.

I don't understand how this matrix can represent an image. In particular, I expect to see a 3D matrix, whose third dimension represents RGB channels. If a pixel is represented by one 8-bit integer, then the whole image can only have 256 colors, but it is clearly not true.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"imread" defaults the second argument to 0, which means that your image is converted to 8-bit depth grayscale. Therefore you are getting a value from 0 to 255 as a color for each pixel of your image.

Try changing your call as follows to get a 3-channel color image:

```
cv2.imread("yourimage.bmp",1);
```

Comment: Or better, use the predefined constant `cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR` instead of `1`. This makes it clear what is happening even if someone does not remember the values of that particular flag.

Answer (score 2):

refer doc [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html)

```
Mat src1 = imread(inputImageFilename1.c_str(), 1); # make sure flag > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

For someone, still confused, here you go.
I assume the OP is referring to a coloured image. OpenCV represents the image as [Blue, Green, Red] (because BGR was more popular in the 90's compared to RGB).
Let's take an example of a 3 x 3 image. It would be represented as follows: [Image showing a 3D matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62vCA.jpg)

I hope it solves the query.