# cv2.imread returns wrong values?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to take the values from the graph on python, here is what I have written:

```
cv0_0=cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\SA\Summary\Std file\BG spec.png")
...
(y,x,z) = cv0_0.shape
print(x)
print(y)
x_coor = []
y_coor = []
for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        if cv0_0[j,i,0] == 255 and cv0_0[j,i,1] == 0 and cv0_0[j,i,2] == 0:
            x_coor.append(i)
            y_coor.append(j)
            #print('True')
        else:
            pass
print(x_coor)
```

The cv0_0 picture is this [image]

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746934/whats-the-meaning-of-the-values-in-the-opencv-image-representation), It must be the arrays contain value `[255,0,0]`. I have used photoshop to inspect the color code and used `imwrite` to see if the image is true, everything is okay except the values from `imread`

Note: Does anyone have better way to regraph the graph in the image on python? '-'

Comment: I tried with jpg type image and it returned right values,does the format of image affect to the value?

Comment: Did you inspect the read image array and check the value it contains at the index you expect will be `[255, 0, 0]`? It's possible it is read as a float that ranges from 0-1 instead of 0-255.

Comment: I don't know why,I tried to read after converting my images to jpg but the values I get still imply that that is a white image(R=B=G)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi the image has the shape of (1217,1004) so I don't think I can inspect in the data. Moreover,all the values presented that is a full white image,I am not sure what is going on

Comment: Does that include every pixel or just most pixels? Your image has a lot of grey pixels, there is just some red and blue. So it makes sense for most pixels to have the same values for each channel.

Comment: I did `imshow(img)` and found that the pixel at `x=521, y=218` is red. Printing `img[218, 521, :]` gives `[1, 0, 0, 1]`, which is as expected.

Comment: oh,I got it, the values return is [ 3   1 251], I forgot that cv2 return GBR values instead of RBG, thanks @PranavHosangadi for help me identify the position of image

Comment: @nebroth wdym by blue graph? '-'

Comment: can you show your result

Comment: Nvm, I used cv2 and pyplot and as it turned out, they use different channel orders... Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: yeah,when I started to learn cv2, I read about it but totally forgot :v